# Error in gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", x) : 'Calloc' could not allocate memory (226427 of 2 bytes)

Tags: r

I am running the following function:

```
my_func <- function(year_to_process){
  data <- df %>%
    filter(filing_date_year == year_to_process | filing_date_year == year_to_process - 1)
  data <- data[(which(nchar(data$text) > 10000)),]
  data_text <- data %>%
    mutate(doc_id = paste(cik, filing_date_year, sep = "_"),
           text = tolower(text)) %>%
    select(doc_id, text) %>%
    setNames(c("doc_id", "text"))
  # Cleaning the text
  t1_text_processing <- Sys.time()
  docs = VCorpus(DataframeSource(data_text))
  docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
  docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
  docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
  docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
  docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, Remove_my_words_before_stem)
  docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument, language = 'english')
  docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, Remove_my_words_after_stem)
  docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(nchar_rm))
  docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
  t2_text_processing <- Sys.time()
  text_processing_time <- t2_text_processing - t1_text_processing
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(weighting = function(x)
    weightTfIdf(x, normalize = TRUE)))
  tdm_sparse <- removeSparseTerms(tdm, .99)
  t1_cosine_time <- Sys.time()
  cosine_dist_mat <- crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(tdm_sparse)/(sqrt(col_sums(tdm_sparse^2) %*% t(col_sums(tdm_sparse^2))))
  t2_cosine_time <- Sys.time()
  cosine_time <- t2_cosine_time - t1_cosine_time
  saveRDS(cosine_dist_mat, file = file.path(working_directory, "cosine_results", "Cosine", "mgnt_results", paste(year_to_process, year_to_process - 1, "cosine_matrix_mgnt.rds", sep = "_")))

  cols <- colnames(cosine_dist_mat)
  rows <- rownames(cosine_dist_mat)
  colsrows <- as.data.frame(cbind(cols, rows))

  colsrows <- colsrows %>%
    separate(cols, c("id_col", "year_col"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
    separate(rows, c("id_row", "year_row"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(year_row_plus_1 = as.numeric(year_row) + 1,
           rows = paste0(id_row, "_", year_row_plus_1)) %>%
    select(cols, rows)

  ids <- colsrows[colsrows$cols %in% colnames(cosine_dist_mat) & 
                    colsrows$rows %in% rownames(cosine_dist_mat), ]
  res <- melt(cosine_dist_mat[as.matrix(colsrows[colsrows$cols %in% colnames(cosine_dist_mat) & 
                                                   colsrows$rows %in% rownames(cosine_dist_mat), ][2:1])])
  ids_res <- as.data.frame(cbind(ids, res))

  ids_res <- ids_res %>%
    separate(cols, c("id_col", "year_col"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
    separate(rows, c("id_row", "year_row"), "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(compare_year = paste0(year_col, "_", year_row)) %>%
    setNames(c("cols_mgnt", "id_col_mgnt", "year_col_mgnt", "rows_mgnt", "id_row_mgnt", "year_row_mgnt", "value_mgnt", "compare_year_mgnt"))

  write.csv(ids_res,  file = file.path(working_directory, "cosine_results", "final_cosine_results", paste(year_to_process, year_to_process - 1, "cosine_results_mgnt.csv", sep = "_")))

  print(paste("Text Processing Time", text_processing_time, "for", year_to_process, "and", year_to_process - 1))
  print(paste("Cosine Matrix processing Time", cosine_time, "for", year_to_process, "and", year_to_process - 1))
  }
```

Where `years_in_data` looks like:

```
> years_in_data
 [1] 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
```

I apply an `sapply`

```
sapply(years_in_data, my_func)
```

And I get the error:

> Error in gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", x) :    'Calloc' could not allocate
>   memory (226427 of 2 bytes)

The code works for the first few years with the times printed as follows:

```
> sapply(years_in_data, text_to_cosine)
[1] "Text Processing Time 6.91588410139084 for 2005 and 2004"
[1] "Cosine Matrix processing Time 5.06124997138977 for 2005 and 2004"
[1] "Text Processing Time 12.2985820492109 for 2006 and 2005"
[1] "Cosine Matrix processing Time 26.73282289505 for 2006 and 2005"
```

However for the years `2007` and `2006` I get the bad memory calloc error. I have read online of similar problems and people have suggested that there is an error in one or more of the packages but it can`t be because the code words for 2 of the years of data (breaks on the 3rd year).

Any suggestions around this?

Comment: It looks like it bottlenecks on this line: `docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)`. I do not know much about `tm_map`, but could you use `stringr` / `stringi` functions with it? If so, you may have more like with `str_trim` and `str_squish` (I have found that `stringr` / `stringi` outperform `gsub` with a ton of data).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it! I found that I was creating too many data files also, i.e. `df`, `data`, `data_text`, `docs`, etc. which were all taking up space in memory. I replace all these with a single object and it seems to have cleared up enough space and the code is processing. (if it breaks this time I will look to replace the `stripwhitespace` with your suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Also, if you end up solving your own problem, do not forget to post it as the solution / accept it.

Comment: I actually did solve this problem. A few minutes after I posted my earlier comment the code broke again. My laptop is quite old and doesn't have much computing power so I am now running the code on an Amazon AWS without problems. I was running into the memory error at the point `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs, control = list(weighting = function(x)
    weightTfIdf(x, normalize = TRUE)))` and my single CPU was simply running out of memory, now its running on 4 CPUS, so I don't really have a coding solution to give.